# Не работает update и delete hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, grails

Доменный класс:

```
package testgrails12

class Teams {
    Integer id
    String name
    static mapping = {
        table 'teams'
        version false
        name column: 'name'
        id column: 'idteam', sqlType: 'INT(11)', updateable: false, insertable: false
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Контролер:

```
package testgrails12

class BdconnectController {

    def index() {
        def team = Teams.get(4)
        team.name = "123"
        team.save()
        render team.name
        render "hello"
    }
}
```

Я могу получить элемент из бд или записать, но не получается обновлять его либо удалить `team.delete()`

В чем может быть проблема? Ошибок никаких не выскакивает, обновление или удаление просто не происходит.

Comment: В приведенном коде нет не вызываются ни `delete`, ни `update`. Это как минимум затруднит воспроизведение ошибки.

Comment: @defaultlocale в приведенном примере происходит update http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#domainClasses